# Why is enzyme failing to test react highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, enzyme

I am running an enzyme test on my whole app using mount. I want to test all child components so believe this is the best method. I will also test individual components with other tests.

My app.test.js is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from '../../store';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

const StoreInstance = Store();

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  mount(
    <Provider store={StoreInstance}>
            <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
});
```

and when I run my test I get the following error

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8305
      The above error occurred in the <HighchartsChart> component:
          in HighchartsChart (at Graph.js:42)
          in div (at Graph.js:41)
          in div (at Graph.js:37)
          in Graph (at Dashboard.js:39)
          in div (at Card.js:24)
          in div (at Card.js:10)
          in Card (at Dashboard.js:38)
          in div (at Dashboard.js:20)
          in Dashboard (created by Route)
          in Route (at App.js:59)
          in Switch (at App.js:58)
          in main (at App.js:57)
          in div (at App.js:54)
          in App (created by Connect(App))
          in Connect(App) (created by Route)
          in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))
          in withRouter(Connect(App)) (at App.test.js:17)
          in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
          in BrowserRouter (at App.test.js:16)
          in Provider (created by WrapperComponent)
          in WrapperComponent

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      You can learn more about error boundaries at react docs (fb.me/react-error-boundaries).
```

It doesn't actually say what the error is so I am struggling to debug.

I do know that it is complaining about the `<ReactHighcharts />` component which I am using in my graph.js:

```
class Graph extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="graph-container">

          <div className="graph">
                <ReactHighcharts config={this.props.config ? this.props.config : config} /> // config var is defined but I haven't included it
            </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have added the error boundary component as per the suggestion and am now getting the follow error

InvalidCharacterError
        at exports.name (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/validate-names.js:10:11)
        at DocumentImpl.createElement (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:686:5)
        at Document.createElement (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Document.js:92:59)
        at a.createElement (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:18:45)
        at init (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:95:411)
        at Object.createElement (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:65:261)
        at Object.createElement (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:111:222)
        at Object.init (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:104:305)
        at Object.C (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:113:48)
        at getContainer (/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:259:80) { componentStack: '\n    in HighchartsChart (at Graph.js:45)\n    in ErrorBoundary (at Graph.js:44)\n    in div (at Graph.js:43)\n    in div (at Graph.js:39)\n    in Graph (at Dashboard.js:39)\n    in div (at Card.js:24)\n    in div (at Card.js:10)\n    in Card (at Dashboard.js:38)\n    in div (at Dashboard.js:20)\n    in Dashboard (created by Route)\n    in Route (at App.js:59)\n    in Switch (at App.js:58)\n    in main (at App.js:57)\n    in div (at App.js:54)\n    in App (created by Connect(App))\n    in Connect(App) (created by Route)\n    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))\n    in withRouter(Connect(App)) (at App.test.js:17)\n    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)\n    in BrowserRouter (at App.test.js:16)\n    in Provider (created by WrapperComponent)\n    in WrapperComponent' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two open issues on `react-highcharts`. For my understanding the issue is highcharts or jsdom. Please have a look at the following resources:

https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/issues/296

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1791